# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr in tid (FinalizerDaemon)

Tags: android-studio, segmentation-fault, libc

getting this error on  switching between two activities containing images and api calls to server and have used glide to load the images. Can any one give suggestions to solve the issue. Has anybody faced such issues ?

Thanks in advance.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
        signingConfigs {
            config {
                keyAlias 'example'
                keyPassword 'android'
                storeFile file('/home/key/android.jks')
                storePassword 'android'
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.android"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 26
            versionName "2.16"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                debuggable false
                buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "true"
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "true"
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

            staging {
                minifyEnabled false
                buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "true"
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }

        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile project(':library')

        // rest api
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
        compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
        compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
        compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
        compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message, the command that triggers this, and at best a minimal example to reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you for response but the question got solved, it was silly mistake in saving pojo class in Shared Preference.
I was using Android's Location class instead of our Location pojo class.

 new Gson().fromJson(getPrefs().getString("location",""),Location.class);